# writeToFile gives NSUnderlyingError=0x6a3d450 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Is a directory"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, writetofile

I am trying to write file to a path in GCD but it doesn't work. Keeps getting the error "NSUnderlyingError=0x6a3d450 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Is a directory"

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr downloader", NO); 

dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

    NSString* name = [photoDictionary valueForKey:@"title"];
    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:id];

    if(![manager fileExistsAtPath:path]){
        if([manager createDirectoryAtPath: path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil]){ //create intermediate directories
            data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:photoDictionary format:FlickrPhotoFormatOriginal]];  
            NSError *error = nil;
            BOOL success = [data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
            if (!success) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to write to file with error: %@", [error description]);
            }

            if([data writeToFile: path atomically:YES]){
                NSLog(@"data written to file");
            }   
        }
    }
    else{
        if([manager fileExistsAtPath:path]){
            data = [manager contentsAtPath:path];
        }
    }


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() , ^{
        sender.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
        sender.photoData = data;
        sender.photoName = name; 
        //call the segue
        [sender performSegueWithIdentifier:segueTitle sender:sender];
    });       

});

dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

The problem that I am getting is that [data writeToFile: path atomically:YES] is never executed. However, the datapath was indeed created, and when I "po data" the program kinda hangs, so I guess the data was not fully fetched when the writeToFile is called. However I cannot exactly pinpoint the problem and do not know how to solve it. Any advices could be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How about "po path"?  The error message above states clearly that it is trying to write to a directory...you need to append a filename.  What does "path" look like?

Comment: when i po path i get sth like: /Users/tanchen/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/7E26ED55-04F6-4B79-9C65-6A88FACF93C9/Library/Caches/71231321... 71231321 is the unique id of photo. the thing is that the error message actually shows that the directory is created. i also change 71231321 to other custom strings like mytext.txt but still did not have any luck )=

Comment: i also move the block of code outside GCD to eliminate any complications caused by it but still didnt work/

Comment: @borrrden sorry forgot to @ you in the previous comments

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating a directory at the path you're trying to next create the file at. Take that out or create the parent directory instead

Comment: hey mike i changed my code accordingly, so i create directory under path (library/cache/myPhotos) and create another NSString path name storePhotoPath (library/cache/myPhoto/photoID) however i did not createDirectoryAtPath at storePhotoPath. but the problem is:::                 if([manager isWritableFileAtPath:storedPhotoPath]) returns NO and thus i assume that you cannot write to a path unless you create directory for the path? Looking forward to ur reply thx!

Comment: You should almost never try to check if an operation is doable. Just try the operation and see what happens